# calculate a process with operator precedence

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate an arithmetic expression, which is entered as a string (for example, `( 5+4*5-1/8 )`, which will give the result 3). I enter an expression and convert it into an array. First; the result will start with the first element and it will change in the loop. But the problem is operator precedence. How can I use the operator presedence in a loop? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HesapMakinesi {

    private char value[];

    private int count;

    private Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String process;

    HesapMakinesi() {

        System.out.print("Enter the process ");

        process = str.next();

        //System.out.println(islem);

        Initializer(process);

    }

    private void Initializer(String process) {

        count = process.toCharArray().length;

        value = new char [count];

        int i;

        System.arraycopy(process.toCharArray(), 0, value, 0, count);

        //System.out.println(value);

        if(value[0]=='-' || value[0]=='+' || value[0]=='/' || value[0]=='*' ||  // A process cannot start with an operator
                value[count-1]=='-' || value[count-1]=='+' || value[count-1]=='/' || value[count-1]=='*') {

            System.out.println("You have entered a wrong process.Please enter again!!!");

            System.out.print("Enter the process: ");

            process = str.next();

            Initializer(process);

        }



        for(i=0; i<count; i++) { // A process cannot include a character except operators

            if( value[i]!='+' && value[i]!='-' && value[i]!='*' && value[i]!='/' && value[i]!='(' && value[i]!=')' && !Character.isDigit(value[i]) ) {

                System.out.println("You have entered a wrong process.Please enter again!!!");

                System.out.print("Enter the process: ");

                process = str.next();

                Initializer(process);

            }


        }


        for(i=0; i<count-1; i++) { // A process cannot have operators sequantially

            if( !Character.isDigit(value[i]) && !Character.isDigit(value[i+1]) ) {

                if( (value[i] == '+' && value[i+1] == '+' ) || (value[i] == '+' && value[i+1] == '-' ) || (value[i] == '+' && value[i+1] == '*' ) || 
                        (value[i] == '+' && value[i+1] == '/' ) ) {

                    System.out.println("You have entered a wrong process.Please enter again!!!");

                    System.out.print("Enter the process: ");

                    process = str.next();

                    Initializer(process);

                }

                else if( (value[i] == '-' && value[i+1] == '+' ) || (value[i] == '-' && value[i+1] == '-' ) || (value[i] == '-' && value[i+1] == '*' ) || 
                        (value[i] == '-' && value[i+1] == '/' ) ) {

                    System.out.println("You have entered a wrong process.Please enter again!!!");

                    System.out.print("Enter the process: ");

                    process = str.next();

                    Initializer(process);

                }

                else if( (value[i] == '*' && value[i+1] == '+' ) || (value[i] == '*' && value[i+1] == '-' ) || (value[i] == '*' && value[i+1] == '*' ) || 
                        (value[i] == '*' && value[i+1] == '/' ) ) {

                    System.out.println("You have entered a wrong process.Please enter again!!!");

                    System.out.print("Enter the process: ");

                    process = str.next();

                    Initializer(process);

                }

                else if( (value[i] == '/' && value[i+1] == '+' ) || (value[i] == '/' && value[i+1] == '-' ) || (value[i] == '/' && value[i+1] == '*' ) || 
                        (value[i] == '/' && value[i+1] == '/' ) ) {

                    System.out.println("You have entered a wrong process.Please enter again!!!");

                    System.out.print("Enter the process: ");

                    process = str.next();

                    Initializer(process);

                }


            }

        }

        //sCount();

    }

    /*private void Count(){

        double result,temp;

        int i;

        for(i=0; i<count; i++) {

            if( value[i]!= )

        }


    }*/

}
```

Comment: I had to deal with something like this (and a lot more complicated).  Parsing into an array wasn't cutting it.  I had to parse it into a binary tree - and then do the depth-first traversal of the tree to complete the calculations.

Comment: well i only use 4 operators (not '(' and ')' ) because it will be more complicated : ). i have an experience with using binary trees and depth-first traversal and so on in C. but in java we didn't see these subjects. so i am trying to do this in an array. logically in the array the even number elements are the numbers and odd ones are operators. i only think a good algorithm : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment... If you're dealing with a simple expression where you can only have numbers and signs +-/* then you can have a simple approach:

1. split your expression by lowest precedence operators first (+-) remembering the signs.
2. Compute each piece - as now the precedence isn't important, since everything is of the same level
3. sum those computed pieces taking into account the sign of the piece from step 1.

In your example, you'll end up with something like this:

1. (Split by +-) three pieces: (1) 5; (2) 4*5 with sign +; (3) 1/8 with sign -
2. Compute each of the three pieces: (1) 5; (2) 20; (3) 0.125
3. Sum the three pieces with their respective signs: 5+20-0.125 = 24.875

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you do it. You need to parse the expression before evaluating it. I suggest you to read the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: well mate yes i know using stacks for infix prefix notations and so on in C. but in java we hadn't see these subjects yet. so i will use only simple calculations ( not include '(' or ')' ). and i have a string which i convert to an array. so logically the even number of elements are the numbers and odd ones are the operators. and this is where i stick. ı am tryıng to calculate ın a for loop

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't get it. Sorry.